# Requiring a pin instead of password for websites?

Tags: passwords

Curious if this could be a good alternative to passwords. On a website, user can choose to use a pin instead of password. If she does elect to do this (given option) from then on, her account asks for pin only, and via Javascript pop-up.

For users that don't like enabling Javascript, could be good to have a password as normal.

Pop-up may also be good since it is more difficult to keylog, if we present user with on-screen numbers (like in lastpass, or iPhone.) Can even do dragging like in Android.

Do you think this is a good idea, to offer both? Is there anything you would improve or change about the idea?

Comment: Without a doubt it's a bad idea. See thexacre's three points. Keyloggers are way less of a threat than weak passwords. "Key" loggers are also capable of capturing mouse clicks, screenshots, and more, so no work-around is effective.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think this is a great idea, especially as an alternative to a password (rather than in addition to a password):

- A 4 digit pin by itself could be brute forced in ~100 days even if you had a 15 minute lockout for incorrect password attempts.
- Entering 4 digits via your mouse on a screen is probably slower for most people than entering their password via their keyboard (which they're used to typing)
- People are very likely to use some permutation of their year of birth or postcode as their pin

To make this secure a user would still have to log in normally from each machine, which sets a long expiry cookie then each time the user returns to the site they must enter a pin which sets a shorter cookie. This is really only protecting them from someone else using their computer while the user is still logged in via a long term cookie.

Depending on your goals I suggest the following:

- If your goal is stronger authentication then I suggest using multi-factor authentication
- If your goal is to make it easier for users to log in but you don't want to use a longer cookie then remember their username and not password (users can type their password pretty quickly)
- If your goal is to prevent other people snooping on a users computer than this is better addressed on the user end by logging out when they leave their machine.